# Python datetime parsing none dates; ignoring those and defaults

Tags: python, datetime

Dear Python Date and Time Lords,

I am trying to parse dates of which some are clearly not dates but I want to ignore those or use a default date
however I am not making progress.

```
d=datetime(1984, 1, 'May', 0, 0, ignoretz=True, default='05/13/1982')
d.strftime(f'{d:%d/%m/%Y}')
print(d)
#an integer is required (got type str)
```

Does someone have a suggestion, how I can deal with none-dates when going through a list and parsing dates?

Comment: Use a `try`/`except` block to deal with the error?

Comment: I don't see any list in your question. Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first point out some mistakes you have made in your code. I'm hoping this will help you to understand where you have gone wrong.

1. I'm not sure why you think you can pass the argument `default` to the `datetime` constructor. It is not available option. You can see the available arguments in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)
2. `strftime` is a class function returns a new `datetime` object. If you call it on an existing `datetime` object like you do in your example, it does not modify the existing object.
3. You are specifying the date format string as a f string. This is not necessary.

So here is an example of how you could do this:

```
from datetime import datetime

input_string = '05/13/1982'
d = datetime.strptime(input_string, '%m/%d/%Y')

print(repr(d))
# prints datetime.datetime(1982, 5, 13, 0, 0)

# d is a datetime object. If you want it as a unix timestamp int, call .timestamp()
print(d.timestamp())
# prints 390088800.0
```

Answer (score 0):

@Robin Zigmond

Thanks. I think that works!

```
try:
    input_string = 'May 13 1982'
    d = datetime.strptime(input_string, '%m/%d/%Y')
    print(d)
except ValueError:
       print("That was no valid date.")
```